# Narrowing Conversion required while list initialization

Tags: c++, c++11, list-initialization, type-narrowing

I read about narrowing conversion on the cpp reference website. I kind of understood it but what i am not getting is that why is the error present only in the first line.

```
    long double ld = 3.1415926536;
    int a{ld}, b = {ld}; // error: narrowing conversion required
    int c(ld), d = ld;   // ok: but value will be truncated
```

Why is the error only present in first line and not the second?

Comment: Keep in mind that uniform initialization is a newer concept. It was designed with the benefits of hindsight. Also keep in mind that it may not be trivial to change the behavior of long-standing mechanisms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the compiler is required to issue a diagnostic (in your case error) for narrowing **only** for [**list initialization**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization) (a.k.a. **uniform initialization**), introduced starting with C++11. For the pre-C++11 initialization without curly braces, there is no diagnostic required.

See the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization#Narrowing_conversions) documentation for more details.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28466236/3093378) as to why the compiler is only required to issue a warning, not necessarily an error.

Comment: Note that most compilers have options/flags you can enable that will cause them to *also* issue a diagnostic for narrowing conversions of the pre-C++11 form - if you so desire (for gcc this would be `-Wnarrowing`).

Comment: This is not only with new syntax. `int a[] = {ld};` was valid C++03 but became invalid in C++11.

Comment: @hvd I think that's also now considered list initialization, although cannot bet on it.