# anonymous union in initializer list, do not handle the types correctly

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, type-narrowing

anonymous union in initializer list : do not handle the types correctly

this code works weirdly, I'll explain :
nothing to say regards points 1 and 2, works perfeclty

however the behavior referred to points 3 and 4 changes :

1) first if i define :

```
    union {
        uint64_t    integer ;   
        double      real;   
    } ;
```

compiler shows  me error about **narrow conversion** between (double) and (uint64_t), but both have same size, as you can in in assert instruction.

```
C:\prj\cd>g++ -std=c++11 src\prova.cpp -o bin\main.exe
src\prova.cpp: In function 'int main()':
src\prova.cpp:35:6: error: narrowing conversion of '3.3999999999999999e+0' from 'double' to 'uint64_t {aka long long unsigned int}' inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
   t1 = { 1 ,"a",3.4 } ;
  ^
```

2) second if i change order types, compiler do not emits error but after execution show me undefined result at point #4

```
    union {
        double      real;               
        uint64_t    integer ;   
    } ;
```

console output :

```
C:\prj\cd>bin\main.exe
6.6
3
3.4
4611686018427387904
```

We know about g++ 5.3 bugs referring **initializer list** in c++14, as you can found in bugzilla :

```
t1 = { 1 ,"a",{ .real=3.4} } ;
```

Does is this another bugs or an weirdly undefined behavior ?

here others link about narrowing conversion :

[Narrowing Conversion required while list initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44031644/narrowing-conversion-required-while-list-initialization)

[Narrowing conversions in C++0x. Is it just me, or does this sound like a breaking change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434140/narrowing-conversions-in-c0x-is-it-just-me-or-does-this-sound-like-a-breakin)

source code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

typedef struct  token_s
{
    uint8_t         sym ;   
    std::string     tok ;
    union {
        double      real;
        uint64_t    integer ;               
    } ;

} token_t ;

int main ( void )
{
    assert ( sizeof(uint64_t)==sizeof(double) ) ;

    token_t t1 ;

    //#1
    t1.real = 6.6 ; // ok
    std::cout << t1.real << "\n" ;

    //#2
    t1.integer = 3 ; 
    std::cout << t1.integer << "\n" ;

    //#3
    t1 = { 1 ,"a",3.4 } ;   
    std::cout << t1.real << "\n" ;

    //#4
    t1 = { 1 ,"a",2 } ;
    std::cout << t1.integer << "\n" ;   

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: Regarding #4, see [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/struct_initialization#Nested_initialization).  Because you omit the braces during initialization of the nested union, it will always initialize the first member.  Since `t1.integer` is not initialized, reading from it is UB.

Comment: "narrow conversion between (double) and (uint64_t), but both have same size" - they may have the same size in number of bits, but that does *not* mean that they can both accurately represent the same numbers.

Comment: "typedef struct ..." Is a C-ism. Pointless crud in C++.

Comment: src\prova.cpp:95:6: internal compiler error: in reshape_init_class, at cp/decl.c:5462 :   t1 = { 1 ,"a",{ .integer=2 } } ; g++ 5.1 and g++ 5.3 Win